# Do iterators return a reference to items or the value of the items in Rust?

Tags: loops, rust

If I have a vector:

```
let mut v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And I iterate through it:

```
for &item in v.iter() {}
```

Would `&item` here be a reference or a value? It seems like it would be a reference from the `&` part, but reading the details seem to show it's a value???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Do iterators return a reference to items or the value of the items in Rust?

There's no general answer to this question. An iterator can return either. You can find the type of the items by looking up the associated type `Iterator::Item` in the documentation. The documentation of `Vec::iter()`, for example, tells you that the return type is [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html). The documentation of `Iter` in turn has a list of the traits the type implements, and the [`Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator) is one of them. If you expand the documentation, you can see

```
type Item = &'a T
```

which tells you that the item type for the iterator return by `Vec<T>::iter()` it `&T`, i.e. you get references to the item type of the vector itself.

In the notation

```
for &item in v.iter() {}
```

the part after `for` is a *pattern* that is matched against the items in the iterator. In the first iteration `&item` is matched against `&0`, so `item` becomes `0`. You can read more about pattern matching in any Rust introduction.

Another way to iterate over the vector `v` is to write

```
for item in v {}
```

This will *consume* the vector, so it can't be used anymore after the loop. All items are moved out of the vector and returned by value. This uses the `IntoIterator` trait implemented for `Vec<T>`, so look it up in the documentation to find its item type!

The first loop above is usually written as

```
for &item in &v {}
```

which borrows `v` as a reference `&Vec<i32>`, and then calls `IntoIterator` on that reference, which will return the same `Iter` type mentioned above, so it will also yield references.

Comment: Does "&item is matched against &0, so item becomes 0" mean that the Copy trait is applied, so only primitive types are supported?

Comment: @rsalmei Whenever a name is assigned, regardless of whether in a `let` or `match` statement or when passing function arguments, the same rules apply: if the type of the value implements `Copy`, the value is copied, otherwise it is moved. In this case, the value is behind a reference, so it can't be moved, and this will only work for types implementing `Copy`. This aren't necessarily "primitive" types though, since you can implement `Copy` for custom types as well.