# Filtering an iterator on Vec<&str> how to collect back into Vec<&str>

Tags: rust

I am working on my first Rust project, learning as I go. I am trying to filter a vector of &str, however when I attempt to collect the iterator I get this error:

```
a value of type `std::vec::Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&&str`
```

The [documentation of filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) does mention the situation where you get a double reference, following the advice in the documentation I have tried destructuring the references in the argument to the closure, I also have tried adding single or double dereference on the body of the closure.

```
let test = vec!("a", "b", "", "c");
let filt_a: Vec<&str> = tst.iter().filter(|&&x| x.is_empty()).collect();
let filt_b: Vec<&str> = tst.iter().filter(|&x| *x.is_empty()).collect();
let filt_c: Vec<&str> = tst.iter().filter(|x| **x.is_empty()).collect();
```

Any fewer dereferences (or destructured references) also result in exactly the same error.

Adding any additional dereferences just results in the error when you try and dereference a plain `&str`.

Any advice to get me on the right path would be wonderful.

Comment: You need `.copied()` after the filter, or `into_iter()` instead of `iter()`. The latter will result in consuming the original vector.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Just tried them both, I couldnt use 2 dereferences when I use `into_iter()`. `.copied` worked with any of the combinations of dereferences.

Comment: Related: [Do iterators return a reference to items or the value of the items in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780389/do-iterators-return-a-reference-to-items-or-the-value-of-the-items-in-rust) [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter) [Iterating over a slice's values instead of references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613725/iterating-over-a-slices-values-instead-of-references-in-rust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) very helpfully pointed out I either needed either `.copied()` after filter or `.into_iter()` instead of `.iter()`.

[Docs for copied](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied)

[Docs for into_iter for Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html)